# pandas dataframe merge at the end

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How can I merge two dataframes into one, saving only the different rows?

I have tried (with an outer join) the `pd.join` and the `.merge` but they seem to mess with the dataframe columns and they don't solve the problem.

My df looks like:

```
Time (my index) | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume | indicator1 | Indicator2 | ...
```

Every 15 minutes I download new data and save it in df2, then read the old ones in df1.

df2 has rows (defined as index by Time) that df1 doesn't have, I wish I could add them to the end of df2.

Example:

DF1:

```
Time.................................Open.........High..........Low...........Close.........Volume

2021-07-22 07:00:00 32055.25 32145.09 31970.84 31977.06 111.789173

2021-07-22 07:15:00 31979.67 32002.25 31926.26 31986.9 65.247509
```

DF2:

```
Time.................................Open.........High..........Low...........Close.........Volume

2021-07-22 07:15:00 31979.67 32002.25 31926.26 31986.9 65.247509

2021-07-22 07:30:00 31986.9 32030 31926.76 31942.18 62.549173
```

DF3:

```
Time.................................Open.........High..........Low...........Close.........Volume

2021-07-22 07:00:00 32055.25 32145.09 31970.84 31977.06 111.789173

2021-07-22 07:15:00 31979.67 32002.25 31926.26 31986.9 65.247509

2021-07-22 07:30:00 31986.9 32030 31926.76 31942.18 62.549173
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can to merge with outer and indicator=True (which return merge infos, for exemple if the value is only on the right df, only on the left df, or on both

```py
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer', indicator=True)
```

Then, we want only de differences fond on the df2 (right_only)

```py
right_only = merged.query("_merge == 'right_only'").reset_index()['Time'].values == df2.reset_index()['Time'].values
```

Finally, we append the df1 with the right_only values of the df2

```py
df3 = df1.append(df2[right_only])
```

So the complete code is:

```py
merged = merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer', indicator=True)
right_only = merged.query("_merge == 'right_only'").reset_index()['Time'].values == df2.reset_index()['Time'].values
df3 = df1.append(df2[right_only])
```

But like mentioned by @Tejas, you can use concat:

```py
concatenate = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df3 = concatenate.groupby(concatenate.index).first()
```

Comment: the "right_only" method was still outputting strange rows, but the "groupby of concatenate" works perfectly, thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df3.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Nope, if i save it to a excel file to read the data, i can see it doubles the lines, so doubles the size.
it stores the dataframe, then append the same dataframe again but with blank index (time)

Comment: Do reset_index() on both dataframes before concat, if this didn't work, can you please add screenshot of dataframe generated(df.head())